# onMount and event listener

Tags: javascript, svelte

I found a strange behaviour, if I add `document.addEventListener` to click on `onMount`.

1. I have 2 components: App and Nested
2. There is a button in App, which sets `isShow = true`, and Nested component shows.
3. In Nested component there is `onMount` where runs `document.addEventListener('click')`
4. If I click on button in App, Nested component will be mounted, event listener immediately will be attached to document, and click, which was clicked **before** component mount, will be processed.

I guess it happens because Svelte does it in one tick. I tried `await tick()`, but it didn't help.

I see one of solution is wrap `document.addEventListener` to `setTimeout`. It works, but I think it is bad decision.

So, is it behaviour normal or is it a bug?

Here is an example:
https://svelte.dev/repl/c89c272ca6c245dabf8451ba950d10c0?version=3.6.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. The simplest solution is probably to add `{ capture: true }` (or just `true`) as the third argument to `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`: https://svelte.dev/repl/daee8509d6634a68b2cf35e53f660e34?version=3.6.8. This works because the event has left the *capturing* phase by the time the nested event listener is attached, and is now in the *bubbling* phase.